# Using OAuth with SforceServiceLocator

Tags: soap, oauth, salesforce

I'm looking at some code which is using the Salesforce SOAP API to create a session and access data:

```
SoapBindingStub binding = (SoapBindingStub) new SforceServiceLocator().getSoap();
String username;
String password;
[...]
LoginResult result = binding.login(username, password);
binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,result.getServerUrl());
SessionHeader sh = new SessionHeader();
sh.setSessionId(result.getSessionId());
binding.setHeader(new SforceServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), "SessionHeader", sh);
```

Given that I've got an OAuth access token and endpoint, is there a way to adapt this to work correctly without a username/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a *lot* of trial and error -- the answer appears to be the following

1. Use the OAuth Access token as the sessionID
2. The ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY is the Endpoint URL *and* a SOAP API URL, eg: `https://na15.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/21.0`